# Marketing Cloud - How to fetch click data from measures

Tags: marketing-cloud, filters, email-studio

I am trying to fetch click data in Data Extension from measures in Email Studio but getting an error in automation studio..

Firstly I created a measures in which the condition is Click Date is After Today Minus 30 days , created a data filter with the condition Measures >=1 and after that created a filter activity to include that data filter in automatio studio to run in automative way.
please give some idea about the flow of measures and how it works to fetch click data in Data Extension.

Comment: What error are you getting?

Comment: The error occurred during Step 1 of 1:

     1.1 FilterActivity : Test_email_track_click_activity
           Status: Error
           Start Time:  4/20/2018 7:37 AM (UTC-06:00) Central Time (US & Canada)
           Error Time:  4/20/2018 7:37 AM (UTC-06:00) Central Time (US & Canada)

Comment: Automation 'test_click_track' encountered an error and this run did not finish.  Only this much I am getting.

Comment: can you post further details about the filter activity - that seems to be the problem. I would also verify 1. That the source DE still exists 2. The destination DE still exists. 3. The filter that the filter activity uses still exists and is pointed at the correct source DE